# ffmpeg executable not found when compiled with cx_freeze

Tags: python, ffmpeg, cx-freeze, ffmpy

I built an executable from a `ffmpy` code, which I compiled with `cx_freeze`. It works on my PC, as expected, I think it's because I have `ffmpeg` installed on my Windows.

However, I need this compiled code to work on any PC, not only where `ffmpeg` is installed.

When I run the executable, the `ffmpy` error says, `Executable "ffmpeg" not found`.

Here is my `setup.py` for `cx_freeze`. This `setup.py` works for anything I want to compile, except where `ffmpeg` is used.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
from cx_Freeze import setup
from distutils.core import Extension
import os   

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Acer\Miniconda3\envs\updated\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Acer\Miniconda3\envs\updated\tcl\tk8.6'


addtional_mods = ['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format']
setup(
      name = 'programm',
      version = '5.0.1',
      description = 'PyQt',
      options = {'build_exe': {'includes': addtional_mods}},
      executables = [Executable('ffmpy_test.py', base = "Win32GUI")])
```

My question is, how can my `ffmpy_test.py` executable find the `ffmpeg.exe` in the compiled directory. I tried to place the ffmpeg directory in there, but that didn't work.

This is the test code I compiled:

```
from ffmpy import FFmpeg

ff = FFmpeg(inputs={'input.wmv': None}, outputs={'output.mp4': None})
ff.cmd
'ffmpeg -i input.ts output.mp4'
ff.run()
```

Comment: How would you know if `ffmpeg` was even installed on another PC? That's what you need to be asking.

Comment: @l'L'l You mean manually place the ffmpeg directory in the same directory where my python executable is and in the code I would use (/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe`) or just path to the ffmpeg directory, which would be (/ffmpeg)?

Comment: Yes, Python likely wouldn't know where the `ffmpeg` executable would be, so you need to tell it specifically where it resides by using an absolute path, or defining it in the `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @l'L'l Thanks again for your help. You pointed me in the right direction, so I was able to fix the problem. I posted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This import statement: `from ffmpy import FFmpeg` in my python code imports `FFmpeg` class from the `ffmpy` module.This class looks for `ffmpeg.exe` on `C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe`, where `ffmpeg` is installed on my Windows.

Inspired by @l'L'l's comment, I looked into how `ffmpeg` is imported inside the `FFmpeg` class in the `ffmpy` module.

In the `ffmpy` module:

```
class FFmpeg(object):
    """Wrapper for various `FFmpeg <https://www.ffmpeg.org/>`_ related applications (ffmpeg,
    ffprobe).
    """

    def __init__(self, executable='ffmpeg', global_options=None, inputs=None, outputs=None):
        ...
```

So, I needed to change the path in the `executable` argument in order to direct the import statement to the `ffmpeg` directory which I placed manually inside the directory where my code is located.

But, I modified the default value of the `executable` argument in my code, not in the `ffmpy` module, like so:

```
from ffmpy import FFmpeg
import os
d = os.getcwd()
ff = FFmpeg(executable=d+'/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe',inputs={'input.wmv': None}, outputs={'output.mp4': None})
ff.cmd
'ffmpeg -i input.wmv output.mp4'
ff.run()
```